# Types of random number generators and functions that take them as arguments

Tags: c++, random, generator, random-seed, stochastic

Following Stephan T. Lavavej's talk (see [here](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful)), I am using a Mersenne Twister random number generator and am producing random numbers with this kind of code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
int main()
{
  std::mt19937 mt(132);
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0,50);
  for (int i =0;i<10;i++)
  {
     std::cout << dist(mt) << std::endl;
  }
}
```

I would like to shuffle using the `shuffle` function (and not the `random_shuffle`) function (as recommended in the talk again). From [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle), I see the function takes a `URBG&&` as argument.

I don't really understand what a `URBG` is. I tried to feed the `mt19937` instead and it seems to work fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v;
  v.push_back(1);
  v.push_back(2);
  v.push_back(3);
  v.push_back(4);

  std::mt19937 mt(132);

  std::shuffle(v.begin(),v.end(),mt);
  for (int i=0;i<v.size();i++)
  {
    std::cout << v[i] << std::endl;
  }
}
```

**Question**

- What is a `URBG`? Is `mt19937` a subclass of `URBG`?
- Can all types of random number generators given as argument to any function the produce a stochastic result (such as `rand`, `shuffle` or any function from `random.h`)?

Comment: If you look at the reference you link to again, then you will see that `URBG` is a template argument. The type is anything that matches the interface of e.g. the `std::mt19937` class. See the "Type requirements" section of the linked reference for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`URBG` is the name of the template argument; it can be deduced to a variety of types, including `std::mt19937`. If you look further down on the cppreference pages, you'll see:

**g** - a [UniformRandomBitGenerator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/UniformRandomBitGenerator) whose result type is convertible to std::iterator_traits::difference_type

So `URBG` can be any type such that that:

- `URBG::result_type` is an unsigned integer type
- `URBG::min()` returns the smallest `URBG::result_type` that `operator()` could return (strictly less than max)
- `URBG::max()` returns the largest `URBG::result_type` that `operator()` could return (strictly greater than min)
- `URBG::operator()` (applied to the instance provided) returns, in amortized constant time, a value in the closed interval `[URBG::min(), URBG::max()]`
- `URBG::result_type` is convertible to `std::iterator_traits<RandomIt>::difference_type`

The new random number generators typically have some form of state, but if the library function can accept that in some way (for example, by taking a random generator object as std::shuffle does), then sure, they could be used.

Answer (score 2):

A URBG is a Uniform Random Bit Generator. In C++ parlance, it is a function object returning unsigned integer values with a uniform probability distribution (i.e. each possible result is equally likely to occur as any other). These requirements are of course rigorously defined in the standard.

`std::mt19937` instances are URBGs because they satisfy this definition. `std::uniform_int_distribution` instances also satisfy it, so in this case there is absolutely no difference between passing one or the other to `<random>` functions.

However, note that most of the distributions defined in `<random>` are *not* uniform by design, so they cannot be used where a URBG is expected (you will get skewed results).